# How would one evaluate $\sin(72\pi/11)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How would one evaluate $\sin(\frac {72\pi} {11})$?. The prime number in the bottom is getting me stuck. I couldn't see how to use it using the sum of two angles trig identity.

Comment: $\sin(\frac {72\pi} {11})=\cos(\frac {\pi}{22})$

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

$$\sin{\left ( \frac{72 \pi}{11} \right )} = \sin{\left ( \frac{6 \pi}{11} \right )} = \cos{\left ( \frac{\pi}{22} \right )}$$

Now, let $y=\pi/11$.  Then

$$\sin{6 y} = \sin{5 y}$$

Expanding, we find that $\cos{y}$ is the real root of the following equation closest to $1$:

$$32 \cos^5{y} - 16 \cos^4{y} - 32 \cos^3{y} + 12 \cos^2{y}+6 \cos{y} -1=0$$

The quantity desired is then

$$\sin{\left ( \frac{72 \pi}{11} \right )} = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos{y}}{2}} $$

Of course, this evaluation depends on obtaining a closed form for the root of a fifth-degree equation, but that's about as much as you can ask for in this case.

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+cos(pi%2F22)) tells us that the minimal polynomial of $\sin{\left ( \frac{72 \pi}{11} \right )} $ is  $1024 x^{10} - 2816 x^8 + 2816 x^6 - 1232 x^4 + 220 x^2 - 11$. It's the largest root.